# How to pass a list as command line argument in robot framework.?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to pass a list as a command line argument to a robot script using -v option. Since this is not directly supported i am trying some workaround like,

```
robot -v list_arg:a__b__c -E space:_ sample.robot
```

This partly does the job as i can see space separated values when i log them onto console. Like
`a  b  c`. 
However i am unable to iterate over all the list members using FOR.I only see one item("a  b  c") being iterated.

Is there any other elegant way to pass Lists via command line in robot framework.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I don't like it much, I was able to iterate through the list created by `Split String` from `String` library.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
List Of Variables From CLI
    @{list_of_vars}    Split String    ${my_vars}
    :FOR    ${var}    IN    @{list_of_vars}
    \    Log    ${var}    WARN
```

`robot -v my_vars:1_2 -E space:_ -t "List Of Variables From CLI" .`

Comment: is `-E`  deprecated? I'm seeing `option -E not recognized` error, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

When passing data structures to Robot Framework using [Variable Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) would probably be a better option considering you're already converting one structure into a command line compatible one. Adding a variable file uses the `-V c:/path/to/file.ext` syntax.

There are roughly two approaches:

1. **Static**: this is a text file containing the variable structures you seek. This can be in two formats:

   - *Python*: declare the variable structures using regular [Python syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-variables-directly) variable syntax
   - *YAML*: using the [YAML syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml) it is possble to create Robot Framwork lists, dictionaries and strings.
2. **Dynamic**: in this scenario the Robot variables are generated and returned by Python code:

   - *Simple Python Function*: using the `get_variables(arg)`[function](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#getting-variables-from-a-special-function) is the simplest way of returning a dynamic number of variables or a dynamic structure of data.
   - *Dynamic Python Class*: using a [variable class](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#implementing-variable-file-as-python-or-java-class) it's possible to hide certain variables, have a fixed set of variables that are complemented by `init()` based on given input or have all of them generated dynamically.

In most cases the yaml structure is a good way of providing clean way of writing and maintaining an input file:

```
 string:   Hello, world!
 integer:  42
 list:
  - one
  - two
 dict:
  one: yksi
  two: kaksi
 original: &org
  item1: foo
  item2: bar
 reference
  org: *org
```