# How to pass in a dict to a Robot Framework variable from the command-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, command-line, robotframework

I am trying to run the main() from my python test from my RF file with optional keyword-arguments range, domain, and timeout. The test works fine if I hard-code the args in the RF file, but I am hopefully looking to be able to set them from the command-line. I am looking to be able to run the RF file giving any, all, or none of the 3 args listed above with something similar to `robot -v dict_args:range=5_domain=4 -E space=_ run_test.robot`. According to the documentation, "Only scalar variables can be set using this syntax and they can only get string values", but I've seen people on here that are able to write a workaround for lists ([How to pass a list as command line argument in robot framework.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067832/how-to-pass-a-list-as-command-line-argument-in-robot-framework)). Haven't been able to find anything on dicts, any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

run_test.robot:

```
*** Settings ***

Library    my_test
Library    Process

*** Test Cases ***
Run RNTester
    Run Program    ${dict-args}


*** Keywords ***
Run Program
    [Arguments]    &{configuration}
    main    &{configuration}
```

my_test.py:

```
def main(**kwargs):
    #process args
    if 'range' in kwargs:
        range_ = kwargs['range'].split(':')
        range_ = list(map(int,range_))
        if len(range_) == 1:
            range_.insert(0,0)
        test_count = range_[1] - range_[0]
    else:
        range_ = None
        test_count = 0

    if 'domain' in kwargs:
        domain = kwargs['domain'].split(',')
    else:
        domain = None

    if 'timeout' in kwargs:
        timeout = int(kwargs['timeout'])
    else:
        timeout = 30

    run_test(domain, range_, test_count, timeout)
```

**FIXED**
Edited my code to write to a yaml file as @jil suggested. Added a YAMLCreator.py to make a yaml file that my RF file imports. Here's what I now have

run_test.robot:

```
*** Settings ***

Library    my_test
Variables    ${testname}.yaml

*** Test Cases ***

Run RNTester
    Run Program    &{test_name}


*** Keywords ***
Run Program
    [Arguments]    &{configuration}
    main    &{configuration}
```

YAMLCreator.py:

```
import yaml
import sys

def make_dict(**kwargs):

    data = dict()
    for key in kwargs:
        value = kwargs[key]
        data[key] = value
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = sys.argv
    test_name = args[1]
    data = make_dict(**dict(arg.split('=') for arg in args[2:]))

    test_name_dict=dict()
    test_name_dict[test_name] = data

    with open(test_name + '.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(test_name_dict, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries can not be passed from the command line. The best way to import Python structures is to use YAML. This will allow you to load these directly as variables into Robot.

Loading a YAML file can be done in three ways:

1. From the [command-line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) using the `--variablefile FileName.yaml`
2. In the [Settings section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) as `Variable   FileName.yaml`
3. Using a [Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables): `Import Variables  FileName.yaml`

All three approaches have their pros and cons. If you have a fixed data set you need to import then approach 2 will be fine. In case you know which data set you should use at start of Robot Framework, then I'd opt for number 1. If that decision can only be made at run-time of your test, then choose option 3.

Comment: Perfect! I found this to be the best way to do what I want. Edited my question with updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the example code that you linked it could be done like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Keywords ***
Convert String To Dictionary
    [Arguments]    ${my_dict_string}
    @{list_of_items}    Split String    ${my_dict_string}
    ${my_dict} =  Create Dictionary  @{list_of_items}
    [Return]  ${my_dict}
```

But personally I find this way of passing a dict variable quite ugly. If variable file is out of the question, I would probably use `json` and `eval` instead:

```
*** Keywords ***
Convert JSON to Dictionary
    [Arguments]  ${json_string}
    ${d}=  evaluate  json.loads('''${json_string}''')  json
    [Return]  ${d}
```

and then call it like this:

```
robot -v 'dict_args:{"range":5, "domain":4}' run_test.robot
```

Comment: Tried this but got error "Keyword 'Run Program' expected 0 non-keyword arguments, got 1." when executing Run Program. In my test case, I have "     ${dict}    Convert JSON to Dictionary    ${dict_args}" before calling "    Run Program    ${dict}" . How did you get this to work?